# Blueprint 404 errorhandler doesn't activate under blueprint's url prefix

Tags: python, flask, blueprint

I created a blueprint with a `404` error handler.  However, when I go to non-existent urls under the blueprint's prefix, the standard 404 page is shown rather than my custom one.  How can I make the blueprint handle 404 errors correctly?

The following is a short app that demonstrates the problem.  Navigating to `http://localhost:5000/simple/asdf` will not show the blueprint's error page.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

from flask import *
from config import PORT, HOST, DEBUG

simplepage = Blueprint('simple', __name__, url_prefix='/simple')

@simplepage.route('/')
def simple_root():
    return 'This simple page'

@simplepage.errorhandler(404)
def error_simple(err):
    return 'This simple error 404', err

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
app.register_blueprint(simplepage)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def api_get():    
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=HOST,
            port=PORT,
            debug=DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#flask.Blueprint.errorhandler) mentions that 404 error handlers will not behave as expected on blueprints.  The app handles routing and raises a 404 before the request gets to the blueprint.  The 404 handler will still activate for `abort(404)` because that is happening after routing at the blueprint level.

This is something that could possibly be fixed in Flask (there's an open [issue](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/503) about it).  As a workaround, you can do your own error routing within the top-level 404 handler.

```
from flask import request, render_template

@app.errorhandler(404)
def handle_404(e):
    path = request.path

    # go through each blueprint to find the prefix that matches the path
    # can't use request.blueprint since the routing didn't match anything
    for bp_name, bp in app.blueprints.items():
        if path.startswith(bp.url_prefix):
            # get the 404 handler registered by the blueprint
            handler = app.error_handler_spec.get(bp_name, {}).get(404)

            if handler is not None:
                # if a handler was found, return it's response
                return handler(e)

    # return a default response
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```